# Can we write to (target) a Text file using Scribe Workbench?

Tags: text-files, scribe-workbench

I have already worked on `Scribe Workbench` to transfer data from `Sage ERP MAS` to `Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011`.

I am trying to do something new now. I want to write to Text file using Scribe Workbench. So, my Q is that can we use `Scribe Workbench` so that the job has Text file or Excel sheet or XRM as Target?

[Note: I found out that `Scribe Online` is able to do that. But, I want to know whether it is possible with `Scribe Workbench` or `Scribe Insight`?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Scribe Insight supports writing to a file (text, Excel etc).
Just setup a connection and create steps just as you would if the target were CRM.

Mike

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mike!
Actually, I am currently not working on that issue. If in future, I work on that one, I will surely consider your suggestion and may come up with any questions, if I have that time. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Hi Mike, now I am working again on similar kind of issue. Where can I find the options to use Text file as a target?

Comment: Hello Vikram

Create a connection for the text file and then you can write to it.
I usually use ODBC - so setup an ODBC connection first.
This can all be done from within Scribe.

Mike